# How to do image back projecting correctly?

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv, image-processing

I am working on the following code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

MatND detectContent(Mat image);

MatND getHistogram(Mat image);

int main()
{
    Mat image;


    try
    {
        image = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Penguins.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        cv::rectangle(image,Rect(670,150,60,60),Scalar(255));

        if(!image.data)
        {
            throw 1;
        }
    }
    catch(int a)
    {
        cout << "Image is unable to read" << endl;
    }


    //Following will show the selected location of the image for the histogram
    namedWindow("Image Selected Location");
    imshow("Image Selected Location",image);


    //Following will display the edites image
    namedWindow("Image");
    imshow("Image",image);
    imshow("Image",detectContent(image));

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

MatND detectContent(Mat image)
{


    //Regiion of interest
    Mat imageROI = image(Rect(900,40,60,100));

    //Get the histogram
    MatND hist = getHistogram(imageROI);

    //Normalizing the histogram
     cv::normalize(hist,hist,1.0);


    //Backprojecting the image
    MatND result;

    float *rangeArray;
    rangeArray[0] = 0.0;
    rangeArray[1] = 255.0;

    const float *rans[1];
    rans[0] = rangeArray;

    int *channels[1];
    channels[0] = 0;

    cv::calcBackProject(&image,1,0,hist,result,rans,255.0);

    return result;
}

MatND getHistogram(Mat image)
{
    MatND hist;

    int histSize[1];//Number of bins
    float hRanges[2];//Max and Min pixel values
    const float *ranges[1];
    int channels[1];//Only one channel will be used

    histSize[0] = 256;

    hRanges[0] = 0.0;
    hRanges[1] = 255.0;

    ranges[0] = hRanges;

    channels[0] = 0;

    cv::calcHist(&image,1,channels,Mat(),hist,1,histSize,ranges);

    return hist;
}
```

When I run this code, the "back projected" image is 100% black! The other image, named as "Image Selected Location" will draw a white rectangle around the selected location of the image for histogram. I will display that image below

[image]

Why my back projected image is 100% black?

Comment: are you sure it is 100% black? may be it is a very low value. Also, backprojection works good for color histograms.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: Thank you for the reply and Sorry for the delay of my comment. Yea, it is pure black. If you are a windows user you can test this case easily because the penguin image is available in your "sample images" folder. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tested the code you posted on OS X (results below), and it works properly, with two minor corrections.[image: Backprojected penguins]

In `detectContent()` you declare `float *rangeArray;` without initializing it, and then immediately dereference it. This is a bug. Instead, declare it as:

```
float rangeArray[2];
```

Second, the ranges provided to `cv::calcBackProject()` are exclusive. That means you should change the line

```
rangeArray[1] = 255.0;
```

to

```
rangeArray[1] = 256.0;
```

if you wish to include the full range of 8-bit values. Otherwise, any pixel with a value of `255` will not be included in the histogram.

Also, the line `imshow("Image",image);` in `main()` is unnecessary. The image to be shown is immediately replaced by the result of `detectContent()` in the next line.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you a lot! Great help with great explanation! Thanks again and +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your range to 1 on this line

cv::calcBackProject(&image,1,0,hist,result,rans,255.0);

and setting the uniform flag

I got this from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calcbackproject#calcbackproject)